# Solving Fick's second law of diffusion in 1D sphere using FiPy

Tags: python, pde, fipy

I'm trying to solve the second law of diffusion for spheres PDE using fipy. I've checked the documentation but there's no example for such a case, so I was wondering if it is actually possible to do it, as I was not successful reaching for the adequate equation definition structure. I consider azimuthal and zenith angular symmetries, so the equation I need to solve results in the following.

[image: equation]

Of course, boundary conditions are fixed at r=0 and r=R at fixed values and the initial concentration is also known. I also tried to follow the ideas presented in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52242891/1d-spherical-grid-in-fipy) but didn't get any clear result for it. Any ideas would be welcomed.

The code I'm using at the moment is the following:

```
from fipy import Viewer, TransientTerm, DiffusionTerm, SphericalGrid1D, CellVariable
from builtins import range

nr = 100 #number of cells on the mesh
r_ca = 8.5e-6 #sphere radius

Iapp = -1*1.656 #Current [A] discharge
F = 96485.33212331001 #Faraday constant
S_ca = 1.1167 #Surface of cathode
D_ca = 1e-14 #Diffusion coef.

Xinit_ca = 0.4952 #[p.u.]
Xinit_an = 0.7522

BoundaryR0 = 0 #Fixed flux at r=0
BoundaryR1_ca = -Iapp/(S_ca*F) #Fixed flux at r=r_ca

mesh = SphericalGrid1D(nr=nr, Lr=r_ca) 
X_ca = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, name='Concentration cathode', value=Xinit_ca) 
X_ca.faceGrad.constrain(BoundaryR1_ca, mesh.facesRight) #Fixed flux boundary condition
X_ca.faceGrad.constrain(BoundaryR0, mesh.facesLeft)

eq_ca = TransientTerm() == DiffusionTerm(coeff=D_ca) # dX/dt = D/r^2 * d/dr(r^2*dX/dr)

tstep = 1 #s
Nstep = 1000

for step in range(Nstep):
    eq_ca.solve(var=X_ca, dt=tstep)

viewer = Viewer(vars=X_ca, datamin=0.45, datamax=0.8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things going on:

- Some solvers don't like the spherical mesh, probably because of the enormous range in cell volumes. The SciPy `LinearLUSolver` seems to work. Judicious preconditioning might help other solvers.
- Eq. (45) in [the paper you linked below](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.electacta.2019.134797) defines the *flux*, but you are constraining the gradient. You need to divide by the diffusivity.
- `X_ca` is in units of `[stoichiometry]`, but `BoundaryR1_ca` is in units of `mol/(m**2 * s)` (or `mol/m**4` after dividing by `D_ca`. You need to divide by `C_ca_max` to get `[stoichiometry]/m`, as you're solving something halfway between Eq. (43) and Eq. (52).
- No-flux is the natural boundary condition for FiPy, so there's no need to constrain at `mesh.facesLeft`.
- The gradient at `mesh.facesRight` should be constrained to a vector (even in 1D).

With the changes below, I get behavior that looks consistent with Fig. 7 in [Mayur *et al.*](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.electacta.2019.134797).

```
diff --git a/spherical.py b/spherical.py
index e6c2969..1eee346 100644
--- a/spherical.py
+++ b/spherical.py
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-from fipy import Viewer, TransientTerm, DiffusionTerm, SphericalGrid1D, CellVariable
+from fipy import Viewer, TransientTerm, DiffusionTerm, SphericalGrid1D, CellVariable, LinearLUSolver
 from builtins import range
 
 nr = 100 #number of cells on the mesh
@@ -13,19 +13,22 @@ Xinit_ca = 0.4952 #[p.u.]
 Xinit_an = 0.7522
 
 BoundaryR0 = 0 #Fixed flux at r=0
-BoundaryR1_ca = -Iapp/(S_ca*F) #Fixed flux at r=r_ca
+BoundaryR1_ca = -Iapp/(51410*D_ca*S_ca*F) #Fixed flux at r=r_ca
 
 mesh = SphericalGrid1D(nr=nr, Lr=r_ca) 
 X_ca = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, name='Concentration cathode', value=Xinit_ca) 
-X_ca.faceGrad.constrain(BoundaryR1_ca, mesh.facesRight) #Fixed flux boundary condition
-X_ca.faceGrad.constrain(BoundaryR0, mesh.facesLeft)
+X_ca.faceGrad.constrain([BoundaryR1_ca], mesh.facesRight) #Fixed flux boundary condition
 
 eq_ca = TransientTerm() == DiffusionTerm(coeff=D_ca) # dX/dt = D/r^2 * d/dr(r^2*dX/dr)
 
 tstep = 1 #s
 Nstep = 1000
+solver = LinearLUSolver()
+
+viewer = Viewer(vars=X_ca, datamin=0.45, datamax=0.8)
 
 for step in range(Nstep):
-    eq_ca.solve(var=X_ca, dt=tstep)
+    eq_ca.solve(var=X_ca, dt=tstep, solver=solver)
+    if step % 100 == 0:
+        viewer.plot()
 
-viewer = Viewer(vars=X_ca, datamin=0.45, datamax=0.8)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can't get the answer right. I try to follow the overall steps presented in [here](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/diffusion/generated/examples.diffusion.mesh1D.html#module-examples.diffusion.mesh1D) to obtain the results presented in [here] (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0013468619316688) on the Fig.7. My actual code looks like this: [Code](https://ibb.co/8cG5vP8). Is really the radial equation defined as a standard diffusion equation in fipy?

Comment: Yes, FiPy solves $\nabla\cdot D \nabla C$. In a spherical geometry, this is a spherical equation. Please provide your code. Screenshot of code is not code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a newcomer, I edited the question so the whole code is displayed there. If there's something else I can do to improve the quality of the question and subsequently the answer let me know. Regards.